# В ASP .Net Web Forms создать кнопки передать данные в метод

Tags: c#, asp.net-webforms, webforms

В ASP .Net Web Forms пробую создать кнопки и добавить в определенное место, привязать к событию щелчку по ней, передать уникальный индификатор кнопки в метод. Саму кнопку добовляю так

```
for(int i; i<=10;i++)
 { %> 
<asp:Button ID="Button<%=i%>" runat="server" > 
<%}
```

Тут создается id прямо с %. Как создать кнопку с уникальным  индификатором или с другим атрибутом и передать его в метод `click`?

Comment: "Саму кнопку добовляю так" - и что, добавляется?

Comment: @Igor Ничего не добавляется вываливается с ошибкой  "Button1 <%=i %>' не является допустимым идентификатором"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В маркапе, во время генерации html страницы, поздно создавать серверные контролы. Создавайте их в `Page_Load` или, в крайнем случае, в `Prerender`.

Comment: Как раз во время генерации страницы на сервере <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click1" Text="Button" /> Вместо ID и Text подставить свои значения

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Button button = new Button();
                button.Text = "btn" + i;
                button.ID = "btn" + i;
                button.Click += Button_Click;
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(button);
                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            } Сделал так, добавил Page_Load